Occurrences of each weekday for a specific month in conjunction to a text of another column
We need to count how many Mondays, Tuesdays etc. on a specific month have a specific letter at the next column. e.g How many Sundays of March 2024 have the letter "π" in the column B? (The result should be 1)
So far, the following formula does not take in consideration column B and is also inefficient.
The formula at A2 of the second sheet is:
=SUMPRODUCT(
Ωράριο.$A:$A>=DATE(LEFT($A2;4);RIGHT($A2;2);1);
Ωράριο.$A:$A<=DATE(LEFT($A2;4);RIGHT($A2;2);31);
TEXT(Ωράριο.$A:$A;"ddd")=B$1
)

This calculation produces the correct result and takes about 30 seconds.
Copying the formula to the adjacent 6 cells produces correct results and calculation is very slow taking about 3 minutes.
This is the first sheet and is called "Ωράριο". Column A contains dates and column B contains text:

This is the second sheet and is using data from the first sheet:


You could first create new columns with days and month-year data (the later in the same format as in the second sheet), so they don't need to be re-calculated every time. Using =LEFT(A1,3) and =CONCAT(RIGHT(A1, 4),"-",MID(A1,9,2)):
 Thu, 28-03-2024     p    Thu    2024-03
 Fri, 29-03-2024     p    Fri    2024-03
 Sat, 30-03-2024     a    Sat    2024-03
 Sun, 31-03-2024     p    Sun    2024-03
 Mon, 01-04-2024     a    Mon    2024-04
 Tue, 02-04-2024     a    Tue    2024-04
 Wed, 03-04-2024     a    Wed    2024-04
 Thu, 04-04-2024     r    Thu    2024-04
 Fri, 05-04-2024     r    Fri    2024-04
 Sat, 06-04-2024     p    Sat    2024-04
 Sun, 07-04-2024     p    Sun    2024-04
 Mon, 08-04-2024     a    Mon    2024-04
 Tue, 09-04-2024     p    Tue    2024-04
 Wed, 10-04-2024     p    Wed    2024-04
 Thu, 11-04-2024     p    Thu    2024-04
 Fri, 12-04-2024     r    Fri    2024-04
 Sat, 13-04-2024     a    Sat    2024-04
 Sun, 14-04-2024     a    Sun    2024-04
 Mon, 15-04-2024     a    Mon    2024-04

Then you can use COUNTIFS with the three conditions: =COUNTIFS($Schedule.$B:$B, "p", $Schedule.$C:$C, B$1, $Schedule.$D:$D, $A2)
Days     Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
2024-03   0   0   0   1   1   0   1
2024-04   0   1   1   1   0   1   1
2024-05   0   0   0   0   0   0   0


Although column A should have been used as dates and not text, COUNTIFS was a great suggestion and it worked very efficiently.

You can write two column-helpers then use a pivot table. On your first sheet :
in C1 :
=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),1),"aaaa-mm")

in D1 :
=TEXT(WEEKDAY(A2),"[$-408]jjj")


Pivot table on your second sheet with :

Months in rows field
Days in columns field
Letters (hours ?) in the filter field
Operation : Count Letters

Output :


In =TEXT(WEEKDAY(A2),"[$-408]jjj") the [$-408] part, which is called LCID, directs Libreoffice Calc to use the el-GR local settings. More about LCID.... Thanks for the heads up.
